# Android : Looping through big numbers of ImageButtons

Tags: android, graphics

I am applying images to my ImageButtons in code, but I'm wondering if there is a better way than shown in my example. I definitely know that it's not the correct way to do it as it can take way too much time with large numbers of views.

```
    btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
    btn2.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
    btn3.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
    btn4.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
    btn5.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);

btn1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    btn1.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    btn2.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    btn2.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    btn3.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    btn3.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    btn4.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    btn4.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    btn5.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    btn5.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the root view in the activity, cast it to `ViewGroup`, get all children, check their type and update accordingly. Namely as follows,

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
int children = rootView.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < children; i++) {
    View view = rootView.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
        ((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
        ((ImageButton) view).setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        ((ImageButton) view).setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Copied the code, but it didn't do anything. Did I have to add/change something? Sorry, I'm new to graphics.

Comment: this should replace the code snippet you provided, since it does the same thing as what you already posted, but dynamically. I think this is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Yeah, looks like what I want, but it currently does nothing when I run it.